# How to translate a button and use its new position?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I want button to move on screen and change its position from where i could use it again.
I have a code bt dont know how to stop it at new position.

```
    final  Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,100);
    animation.setDuration(1000);
    button.startAnimation(animation);
```

please help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method, it will persistent the animation

```
animation.setFillAfter(true);
```

public void setFillAfter (boolean fillAfter)

Since: API Level 1

If fillAfter is true, the transformation that this animation performed will persist when it is finished. Defaults to false if not set. Note that this applies to individual animations and when using an AnimationSet to chain animations

Comment: It is making button stay at new position but i cant use it again?

Comment: what do you mean by i con't use it again?

Comment: Try calling setOnClickListener again on the button

Answer (score 0):

create an animation, move it to desired position and set listener to animation and when animation ends, move the button to new position .

Comment: I have got some code to move the button,bt I couldnt use it at new position.Eg clicklistener is not working there.